# git: after merge conflicts, checkout for resetting files, but now merge doesn't reapply

Tags: git, merge, git-checkout

At some branch X I did

```
git merge master
```

But there was some conflicts. I did a mistake during resolving the conflicts, (basically doing `git add` when I should have done `git rm` to confirm some local deletes)

To cancel those errors, I did

```
git checkout -- folder/
```

which removed everything from cache. But now I did attempted again the merge and I get this:

> fatal: You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists). Please,
>   commit your changes before you can merge.

What should I do to avoid this message?

Answer (score 3):

Typically, to roll back a merge that generated conflicts you'd do [`git merge --abort`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge).